# SDL 8.5 Experience Optimisation - Deployer Committing Failure

Tags: deployer, experience-optimization, web8.5

Environment - SDL Web 8.5 Experience Optimisation Installation / Combined Deployer / Scaled-Out

I believe it's failing on the section which was requested to be added in via the docs ("Tridion-Process-PostCommit") - https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-E87C6C4B-C7F7-432D-8649-9EE6BCC613C8&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-E87C6C4B-C7F7-432D-8649-9EE6BCC613C8.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E87C6C4B-C7F7-432D-8649-9EE6BCC613C8

Looks to me like I'm missing a JAR or something. All files were copied from the 8.5 Installation Folder as instructed in the docs.

```
2017-07-20 13:51:04,233 DEBUG StepActor - Start step 'Optional[BasicStep [id=SmartTargetDeploy, factory=com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory]]' for 'tcm:0-166-66560'
2017-07-20 13:51:04,233 DEBUG HybridStateStore - Creating new step entity for execution id: tcm:0-166-66560, pipeline id: Tridion-Process-PostCommit and step id: SmartTargetDeploy
2017-07-20 13:51:04,248 DEBUG BasicExecutableStepFactoryManager - Providing ExecutableStep for PipelineId: Tridion-Process-PostCommit and StepId: SmartTargetDeploy
2017-07-20 13:51:04,248 DEBUG TridionDeployerStepAdapter - Create module based on configuration: Module(Class=com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredHopperDeployerModule, Type=SmartTargetDeploy)[Transformer(Class=com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer)]
2017-07-20 13:51:04,248 ERROR ModuleFactory - Unable to create module
com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to load Module
    at com.tridion.deployer.ModuleFactory.createModule(ModuleFactory.java:115)
    at com.tridion.deployer.ModuleFactory.createModuleOnPreference(ModuleFactory.java:72)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionDeployerStepAdapter.configure(TridionDeployerStepAdapter.java:59)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory.processConfiguration(TridionExecutableStepFactory.java:169)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory.create(TridionExecutableStepFactory.java:140)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.step.BasicExecutableStepFactoryManager.getStep(BasicExecutableStepFactoryManager.java:44)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$execute(StepActor.scala:53)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:44)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:27)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: com.tridion.util.TridionReflectionException: Unable to load request class, was not found on classpath
    at com.tridion.util.ReflectionUtil.loadClassInstanceWithTypes(ReflectionUtil.java:65)
    at com.tridion.deployer.ModuleFactory.createModule(ModuleFactory.java:109)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredHopperDeployerModule
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sdl.delivery.service.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:45)
    at com.sdl.delivery.service.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:31)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.tridion.util.ReflectionUtil.loadClassInstanceWithTypes(ReflectionUtil.java:59)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you post your deployer configuration file? or are you using the Combined Deployer or Scaled-Out?

Comment: Could you list the files and folders you have in the 'services' folder of your deployer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The requested added pipelines in the deployer-conf.xml have a spelling mistake in the documentation

```
<Module Class="com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredHopperDeployerModule"
<Module Class="com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredHopperUndeployModule"
```

should be

```
<Module Class="com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperDeployerModule"
<Module Class="com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperUndeployModule"
```

Hopper should be a lowercase 'h'

You will also see another issue if you follow the documentation. They tell you to add the extra XO Pipelines to the bottom of the file. The XO Pipeline sections must be *before* the "Tridion-Cleanup" section, otherwise you get an error.